# JavaScript Error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error and I cannot figure out why:

> this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
>                                ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at Object.addDishToCourse

```js
   let menu = {
        _courses: {
            appetizers: [],
            mains: [],
            desserts: [],
            get appetizers() {
                return this.appertizers;
            },
            set appetizers(newAppetizer) {
                this.appetizers = newAppetizer;
            },
            get mains() {
                return this.mains
            },
            set mains(newMain) {
                this.mains = newMain;
            },
            get desserts() {
                return this.desserts;
            },
            set desserts(newDessert) {
                this.desserts = newDessert;
            },
        },
        get courses() {
            return {
                appetizers: this._courses.appetizers,
                mains: this._courses.mains,
                desserts: this._courses.desserts
            };
        },
    
        addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
            const dish = {
                name: dishName,
                price: dishPrice,
            };
    
            this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
        },
    
        getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
            const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
            return dishes[randomIndedx];
        },
        generateRandomMeal() {
            const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("appetizers");
            const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("mains");
            const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("desserts");
            const totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
            return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name}, ${dessert.name}. Your total is $${totalPrice}.`
        }
    
    }
    
    
    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Ceasar Salad', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Prawn Coctail', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Garlic Bread', 3.50);
    
    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Lasagna', 9.75);
    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Ribeye Steak', 14.95);
    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Fish & Chips', 12.95);
    
    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cheese Cake', 4.50);
    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Creme Brule', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cheese Board', 3.25);
   
let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();

console.log(meal);
```

Comment: Does `console.log(this._courses[courseName]);` yield an array? I bet it's `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: You have a typo in your appetizers getter: `return this.appertizers` has an extra r.

Comment: What IceMetalPunk said: `appetizers: undefined`

Comment: @mwilson what part of the code am I supposed to insert that and see the result? I am not using any known IDE, I am just trying this on an online JS engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```js
let menu = {
        _courses: {
            _appetizers: [],
            _mains: [],
            _desserts: [],
            get appetizers() {
                return this._appetizers;
            },
            set appetizers(newAppetizer) {
                this._appetizers = newAppetizer;
            },
            get mains() {
                return this._mains
            },
            set mains(newMain) {
                this._mains = newMain;
            },
            get desserts() {
                return this._desserts;
            },
            set desserts(newDessert) {
                this._desserts = newDessert;
            },
        },
        get courses() {
            return {
                appetizers: this._courses.appetizers,
                mains: this._courses.mains,
                desserts: this._courses.desserts
            };
        },

        addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
            const dish = {
                name: dishName,
                price: dishPrice,
            };

            this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
        },

        getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
            const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
            return dishes[randomIndex];
        },
        generateRandomMeal() {
            const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("appetizers");
            const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("mains");
            const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse("desserts");
            const totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
            return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name}, ${dessert.name}. Your total is $${totalPrice}.`
        }
    }

    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Ceasar Salad', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Prawn Coctail', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Garlic Bread', 3.50);

    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Lasagna', 9.75);
    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Ribeye Steak', 14.95);
    menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Fish & Chips', 12.95);

    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cheese Cake', 4.50);
    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Creme Brule', 4.25);
    menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cheese Board', 3.25);

    let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();

    console.log(meal);
```

Comment: You got a duplicated index: 
_courses.appetizers as variable
_courses.appetizers as getter/setter

you have to change the variable to _courses._appetizers

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a property getter and a property of the exact same name. One overrides the other. However, there isn't really a point to a property getters and setters here since you are implementing the default behaviour.

If you declare `_courses` as:

```
    _courses: {
        appetizers: [],
        mains: [],
        desserts: [],
    }
```

And leave off the getters setters, it should work as you expect.

---

If you do want to use property setters and getters here, you will have to give the underlying property that stores the values a different name than the getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
get appetizers() {
    return this.appertizers; // <-- Typo: should be appetizers
}
```

Additionally, if you are still having issues, make sure you are getting the result you're expecting. For example try running a console log to see if it's yielding the result you're expecting.

```
console.log(this._courses[courseName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you defined _courses inside menu. Instead this._courses point to a variable outside menu that doesn't exist.
You should refere to menu instead of this because the scope of this is not the function. You should change also all the other reference of this in the json

```
this.menu = {
    _courses: {
        ...
    },
    ... 
    addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
        const dish = {
            name: dishName,
            price: dishPrice,
        };

        menu._courses[courseName].push(dish);
    }
}
```